# Transaction fails on Etherscan but succeeds on Tenderly, why is that?

Tags: etherscan, uniswap, evm, goerli, uniswapv2

So I have made a Uniswap V2 Fork and deployed it successfully, added liquidity etc everything successfully, all on Goerli.

But when I am working on my frontend for my main Swap Component(in ReactJS), I weirdly enough cannot make it work, I always get the Metamask Error 32000 or that the GAS estimation failed. I've tried almost everything to make it work but it always gets the same error.

So I basically tried checking if there is something wrong with the contract and I've tried doing the swap via etherscan manually but I always get an estimated gas of 50eth(which I of course don't have). Before you ask, yes I have given the proper amount of allowance to the contract, yes I have a huge spread and yes I have enough liquidity.

I've then used Tenderly to simulate the transaction with the exact same parameters and it instantly said the simulation succeeded.

So my question now is, could it be that it fails because something is up with Goerli or am I wrong? Because if yes I'd be overjoyed and deploy it on Sepolia but I didn't think that something like that could be possible.

If needed I can post my Swap Code later on for you to look through but my main question is concerning Goerli/Tenderly.

Thanks in advance, you guys rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goerli has been super unsteady un unreliable lately. Its [gas prices](https://explorer.bitquery.io/goerli/gas) have been through the roof.

Basically Goerli shouldn't be used anymore for testing dapps. Sepolia is the meant network for dapp testing. Yes, it's missing some integrations, but just have to live with it.

Furthermore, Goerli has been deprecated.